# should a wrapper for viewcontrollers be a viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Design preference.

If you have a view controller wrapper which contains an array of viewcontrollers and you only display one of those viewcontrollers at a time to the user (i.e the currentViewController)

should the class that contains your array of view controllers be a viewcontroller itself?

You could achieve a wrapper by created a class that inherits from NSObject, and then has an attribute property array.

All viewController's should have a 'view', but a wrapper viewController doesn't need a 'view', it just needs to return currentViewcontroller.view to the UIApplication Delegate windows' rootViewController.

All ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a viewController with childViewControllers, and then set the the view of my "container" `viewController` to the `currentViewController.view`

Doing so means that your lifecycle will stay intact and view events, rotation events etc... will all get passed down to the children.

See "Implementing a Custom Container View Controller" at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html